# Convert capacitor Camera result to Blob

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I need to convert the result from the Capacitor Camera plugin to a Blob for upload to Firebase Storage.

I could upload the Base64 string but I already upload Blobs/Files from a Browse button's FileList so I'd like not to change the design of this.

The Camera plugin provides the image data as a Base64 encoded string representing a PNG image.

I've tried the following:

```js
const { Camera } = Plugins;

const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 90,
  allowEditing: true,
  resultType: CameraResultType.Base64
});

const rawData = atob(image.base64String);
const blob = new Blob([rawData], { type: 'image/png' });
```

But the blob ends up not being a valid image.

Any help is appreciated.

Using: @angular/core: 9.1.4, @ionic/angular: 5.1.0, @capacitor/core: 2.1.1

Comment: you can upload a base64str to firebase... there is no need for the conversion, You can also used fetch to read from filesystem directly into a blob.

Comment: Yes, I mention this. I'm already uploading image binaries from the "Browse" function in my code. I'd like not to change the format that I'm storing images in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to take the byte characters provided by `atob` and convert it to a byte array, which can then be used to generate a `Blob`:

```ts
const rawData = atob(image.base64String);
const bytes = new Array(rawData.length);
for (var x = 0; x < rawData.length; x++) {
    bytes[x] = rawData.charCodeAt(x);
}
const arr = new Uint8Array(bytes);
const blob = new Blob([arr], {type: 'image/png'});
```

Answer (score 15):

I use this:

```ts
import {decode} from "base64-arraybuffer";

const cameraPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
    resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
}

const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(decode(cameraPhoto.base64String))], {
    type: `image/${cameraPhoto.format}`,
});
```

and if it needs to be converted to a file:

```ts
const file = new File([blob], "Name", {
    lastModified: moment().unix(),
    type: blob.type,
});
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Thanks.